# Meaning of SigQuit in Swift 3, Xcode 8.2.1

Tags: swift, swift3, xcode8, ios10

I am trying to create a custom keyboard in iOS 10 that acts like a T-9 keyboard. When switching to my custom keyboard, the app extension reads in a list of about 10,000 words from a txt file and builds a trie out of them.

However, I keep getting a "SigQuit" error when I first try to use the keyboard. Rerunning the keyboard right after it failed seems to usually work. Xcode doesn't give me any explanation for why it failed other than the SigQuit error on some assembly code line.

So, my question is, for what reasons might Xcode throw a SigQuit error? I have tried debugging to no avail, and googling SigQuit does not seem to return any useful information. I considered that my keyboard is using too many resources / taking up too much time on startup, but I checked the CPU usage and it peaked at less than 1%. Similarly, the memory used was something like 25mb which doesn't seem terrible.

Answer (score 1):

Keyboard extensions have a much lower memory limit than apps.  Your extension was likely killed by the operating system.

See:  https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionCreation.html

> Memory limits for running app extensions are significantly lower than
>   the memory limits imposed on a foreground app. On both platforms, the
>   system may aggressively terminate extensions because users want to
>   return to their main goal in the host app. Some extensions may have
>   lower memory limits than others: For example, widgets must be
>   especially efficient because users are likely to have several widgets
>   open at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, seems like you have to Run, then Stop, and it'll run fine on the simulator or device.